# Why is this hello world executable smaller than the one that includes two header files?

Tags: c

learning C and still at a very basic level. Executable compiled from Flav 1 is 83kb. Flav 2 is 48kb.

Why is the version that includes the extra header file smaller? Doesn't seem intuitive. Ty

Flavour 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Flavour 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    if (puts("Hello World") == EOF){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's not the "header file".  The reason for the "size difference" is calling puts() vs. printf().  The printf() function incurs substantial overhead.

Comment: D Yuri, consider trying again with all size optimizations enabled.

Comment: D Yuri, note that the first prints `"Hello World"` while the 2nd prints  `"Hello World\n"`.

Comment: You have 2 completely different programs and you've concluded that the include is the reason for the size difference? Have you done anything to confirm that? Like adding an "if" to the 1st one. Adding "\n" to the first string. Including stdlib in the first? Using puts in the first ? Removing the if from #2 or the \n or the include. I know it takes you in the wrong direction in this case, but EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS could be bitwise operations.

Comment: Headers usually just contain declarations, not much code or data. So they don't increase the size of the executable much.

Comment: @paulsm4 Unless they're linking statically, that overhead will be in a shared library, not the executable.

Comment: change to `printf("Hello World\n");` most optimizing compilers will change the call to `puts` and your executable should be the same.

Comment: did you enable optimizations and strip symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Using an include does not make your program larger. When loading your program, the os loads the libraries needed into memory. Those can also be shared by multiple processes. This is done, to prevent every process loading for example stdlib.h and math.h functions. Your program only needs to know which header it needs. An exception is static linking. With static linking the executable contains the needed library functions, thus making the executable more portable, but larger.

Answer (score 0):

printf does have a bigger overhead when compiled.

Plus the compiler won't include functions inside `<stdlib.h>` since they're not used.
(puts is contained inside the `<stdio.h>` header file)